# R stats wilcox.test returns anomalous P = 1 for two.sided test

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm running a series of Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney tests using wilcox.test from the stats package in R.  I keep getting results where P = 1 for a two-sided test.  I have pulled out the simplest case and converted the raw numbers to integer ranks (which gives the same result because this is a ranks-based test):

```
# unique values from 1 to 14, arranged in 2 sets
x <- c(5, 10, 8)
y <- c(9, 7, 6, 13, 1, 2, 12, 14, 11, 4, 3)
wilcox.test(x, y, alternative = "two.sided")
# for comparison 
wilcox.test(x, y, alternative = "less")
wilcox.test(x, y, alternative = "greater")
```

I have two questions: (academic) what is happening here?  (practical) how can I get a more reasonable P value?  The context here is that I'm doing multiple tests and combining P values using Stouffer's method, which doesn't work when P = 1 for one of the results. So, this behavior is ruining my strategy.

I'm pretty sure that what is happening is that I'm repeatedly stumbling on cases where the chance of x being ranked lower than a randomly chosen y is exactly 0.5.   If this is true, then simplest case must be

```
x <- 2
y <- c(1, 3)
```

and this also gives P = 1.  It doesn't matter whether I'm using wilcox.test from the stats package or wilcox_test from the coin package.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.  For the examples you give, the probability of an observation from *x* being greater than an observation from *y* is very close to 0.5.

One statistic to evaluate this is Vargha and Delaney's *A*, which is the probability of an observation from the first group being greater than an observation from the second group.  Cliff's *delta* is linearly related to this.

```
if(!require(effsize)){install.packages("effsize")}

x <- c(5, 10, 8)
y <- c(9, 7, 6, 13, 1, 2, 12, 14, 11, 4, 3)

library(effsize)

VD.A(x,y)

   ### Vargha and Delaney A
   ### 
   ### A estimate: 0.5151515 (negligible)
```

This is so close to 0.50 that you would have to increase your sample size over 500 times to get a significant difference.

```
X = rep(x, 589)
Y = rep(y, 589)

wilcox.test(X, Y)

   ### Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
   ### 
   ### data:  X and Y
   ### W = 5897700, p-value = 0.04993
```